# Unexpected behavior of pointer to pointer using shared_ptr in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers

I am confused by the behavior of pointers to pointers in C++ when using smart pointers.

In the following compilable code example you can see that reassigning the raw pointer `pA` affects the pointer to pointer `ppA` but this is not the case when using `std::shared_ptr`. This seems like highly counter-intuitive behavior.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    // compare the functionality of raw and smart pointers
    int* pA = new int(1);
    int* pB = new int(2);
    shared_ptr<int> pAsmart(new int(1));
    shared_ptr<int> pBsmart(new int(2));

    // pointer to a pointer
    int** ppA = &pA;
    shared_ptr< shared_ptr<int> > ppAsmart = make_shared< shared_ptr<int> >(pA);

    cout << **ppA << endl; // prints 1
    cout << **ppAsmart << endl; // prints 1

    pA = pB;
    pAsmart = pBsmart;

    cout << **ppA << endl; // prints 2
    cout << **ppAsmart << endl; // prints 1 (huh?)


}
```

Comment: That's because `ppAsmart` doesn't point to `pA`.

Answer (score 0):

`shared_ptr<shared_ptr>` is not the same as a pointer-to-pointer. `ppAsmart` holds the original `shared_ptr` that `make_shared()` returned. You are not doing anything to make `ppAsmart` point at anything else, so it is still holding a `shared_ptr<int>` that is still pointing at the original `pA` object, whose value is 1.  After creating `ppAsmart`, you are then reassigning `pA` to point at the original `pB` object, whose value is 2, and `ppA` is still pointing at the `pA` variable, so dereferencing `ppA` gets you the original `pB` object whose value is 2.  But `ppAsmart` is still pointing at the original `pA` object whose value is 1.  It is not pointing at the `pA` variable itself, like `ppA` is.

Comment: I see, you're quite right. In fact it occurs to me that the lines involving `pAsmart` and `pBsmart` do nothing in this code.  In that case, how does one obtain pointer-to-pointer functionality using just smart pointers?

Comment: Smart pointers are not designed to be used that way. What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm ultimately trying to understand the handle pattern implemented in quantlib library. It turns out various constructors in quantlib accept handles (basically the smart equivalent of a pointer-to-pointer), see p. 237 of https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13584583/qlbook/appendixA.pdf for details

Answer (score 0):

`ppAsmart` points to a new object that points to the object of `pA`; in particular it does not point to `pA`. It remains unchanged. Try to depict a diagram with pointer and pointed objects and you will see.

```
shared_ptr< shared_ptr<int> > ppAsmart = make_shared< shared_ptr<int> >(pA);
```